# würden used in conditionals

Tags: grammar-identification

I got a question about this sentence:

> Wenn du ein bisschen mehr nachdenken würdest, würden dich weniger Leute für einen Vollpfosten halten.

The question is - why is "würdest" used in the same part of the sentence as "wenn"?

Wouldn't it make more sense to put "nachdächtest"?

Answer (score 2):

We have learnt at school: "Wenn  mit würde ist ohne Würde!"

But obvious both of your versions  would be possible:

https://www.verbformen.de/konjugation/nachdenken.htm

Konjunktiv II and Konjunktiv II (Ersatzform)

I would prefer:

> Dächtest du ein bisschen mehr nach, würden dich weniger Leute für einen Vollpfosten halten.

Comment: Nicht nur in gesprochener Form, sondern sogar in der Schriftform empfinde ich diese Formulierung als sehr gestelzt, um es mal vorsichtig auszudrücken. ;-) Es mag aber sein, dass es diesbezüglich regionale Unterschiede gibt.

Answer (score -1):

`Nachdächtest` would be the present form of the conditional 2 (Konjunktiv 2).
With `würden` the future form (*Futur 1*) of `nachdenken` is correctly flexed for the conditional 2 (*Konjunktiv 2*). In English, the phrase would say something like `If you would be going to reflect more`.

The *Konjunktiv 2* emphasises, just as in the English language, that an event or action is very unlikely (read: impossible) to happen and is used in such phrases sarcastically.

[Wikipedia on the Konjunktiv 2](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konjunktiv#Bildung_des_Konjunktivs_II)

Comment: What's "present form of the indicative (Konjunktiv 1)" supposed to mean? And what does Futur 2 have to do with all of that? Anyway, "nachdächtest" is neither indicative nor Konjunktiv 1, but Konjunktiv 2.

Comment: Yes, I've made mistakes looking up the English equivalents of the terms and mixed up quite a bit. I've tried to correct it now.